# SQL Determining differences in near-identical rows

Tags: sql, select

If I have a table of correct data I need to check with my actual table to make sure the data is correct and I have some rows like the following:

```
Data_Check_Table
FRUIT ------- PRICE ------- WEEKS_FRESH ------- SUPPLIER
Apple         $1            1                   Big Co.
Banana        $1            1                   Super Co.
```

and the actual table with this info:

```
Data_Table
FRUIT ------- PRICE ------- WEEKS_FRESH ------- SUPPLIER
Apple         $2            1                   Big Co.
Banana        $1            1                   Super Co.
```

...and assume there are many other rows, some match up fine and others have inconsistencies in certain areas (Maybe the wrong price? Or wrong supplier? Maybe even both.) How would I do a select to find these rows that are inconsistent with the actual data?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: check my answer. If it meets your needs, mark it as accepted please :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Select dt.Fruit,dt.Price, dt.Weeks_Fresh,dtc.Fruit,dtc.Price, dtc.Weeks_Fresh,...
From DataTable dt
FULL OUTER JOIN
DataTable_Check dtc
ON dt.Fruit = dtc.Fruit
AND dt.Price = dtc.Price
.....
Where dt.Fruit IS NULL OR dtc.Fruit IS NULL
```

The full join includes records from each table regardless of whether there is a match, so if either side is null then you know there is a mismatch.

Answer (score 1):

The following to find actual records not matching correct records:

```
select *
from Data_Table
minus
select *
from Data_Check_Table
```

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri: `MINUS` is Oracle's version of `EXCEPT`

Comment: Thanks and sorry, didn't know.